# I'm trying to do some customization for jenkins pipeline parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

For example:
If user selects a choice parameter A it should give two string parameters. If user selects a choice parameter B it should provide four string parameters. if user selects nothing no string parameters ares visible

I only see customization for choice parameters and are there any customization for jenkins string parameters

Comment: https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/ - Not sure if it works with pipeline way of defining params.  If you are using normal parameter definition, this may help.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a choice parameter containing you complex parameter list and then brak that list in yoour script:

**Choice:**

**ChoiceA: param1,param2,param3**

**ChoiceB: param4,param5,param6**

then in the pipeline:

```
 pipeline {
        agent {
            label 'test'
        }
        environment {
            Choice= "${params.Choice}"
        }
        stages{
          stage('build parameter'){
            script{ method_that_returns_parameter_array Choice}
          }
        }
}
```

you can make a shared library and place that method in 'vars' folder and make it available for all the pipelines by putting a line at the top of the script:

```
@Library('jenkinssharedlibrary@branchname-here') _
```